# Should getActiveNetworkInfo() return wifi if wifi is on

Tags: android, networking

My device is Nexus5 with Android 6.0.1, when I turn both wifi and cellular network on, I use the following code to check network type:

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mCtx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                mNetworkType = info.getTypeName();
            }
        }
    }
    Logger.d(TestUtils.TEST_TAG, "type is: " + mNetworkType);
```

the output `type is : MOBILE`, is this expected behavior of this api?

Comment: Try `info.getType()` and see what does it return. 0 or 1.

Comment: there is another method to check that thing...if you want then let me know...

Comment: I tried methods like getType(), getSubType(), android indeed choose to use my 2g instead of wifi. I think this is a bug of android

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Doc it delivers the default network.

[#getActiveNetworkInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network))

> Returns details about the currently active default data network. When
>   connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections.
>   You should always check isConnected() before initiating network
>   traffic. This may return null when there is no default network.
>
> This method requires the caller to hold the permission
>   ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

If you want to check for WIFI in particular you can use the method

[#getNetworkInfo(Network)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network))

> Returns connection status information about a particular Network.
>
> This method requires the caller to hold the permission
>   ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

Comment: how could I prefer wifi? I think android will make wifi default active when wifi is on

Comment: @Charlesjean You have to manually set the default network. [For example like this](http://androidqueries.com/how-replace-default-network-mode-android-based-lenovo-lephone-21341.html)

Comment: I can not find this option on android 6